# Terminal autocomplete slash

Tags: 22.04

I just don't know what happened, but until today I was able to write `.` in the terminal, and pressing TAB would add automatically `/`. This behavior has stopped working suddenly, and it is quite annoying

Edit:

- `bind -v | grep mark-directories` outputs `set mark-directories on`
- `bind -q complete` outputs `complete can be invoked via "\C-i", "\e\e".`

Comment: read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: @graham I think my question is quite clear. If you don't understand it, you may ask for clarification

Comment: @steeldriver the output is `set mark-directories on`

Comment: @steeldriver question updated

Comment: @Raffa how could I check my shell autosourced files? I don't even know what you're referring to...

Comment: @Raffa no `bind ...` found on any of them...

Comment: No `~/.inputrc` found. In `/etc/inputrc` I found `"\e\e[C": forward-word` and `"\e\e[D": backward-word` @Raffa

Comment: @Raffa it did not work...

Comment: ... Please, run this `bind -u complete; bind '"\C-i":complete'`  and then see if completion works in the same shell ... Meanwhile, I might be wrong on `"\e\e\000"` being the sequence for TAP as `"\C-i"` seems to translate to TAP as well as "Ctrl+i" ... I will have to look into it and figure it out.

Comment: *TAP should be TAB in my above comment  ... Yep, I was wrong `"\e"` is the sequence code for the "Esc" escape key and `"\e\e"` will require pressing it twice to activate the binding.

Comment: The `bind` outputs look fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Coursier (from Scala) was installed on my computer, and it made a file (or whatever it was) always present: `.scala-cli.aux`, which made it always a candidate for autocomplete, preventing the slash to be written automatically. Uninstalling it made if work