# Terminal autocompletion not working

Tags: command-line, 22.04

This issue is very simple.

1. Open terminal (I'm using GNOME Shell 42.9)
2. Write down `.`
3. Hit TAB to autocomplete

The expected behavior (which has worked before) after following this steps is to have `./`. However, my terminal won't add `/` automatically.

I have no clue on what changed in the system to break this behavior

**UPDATE 1**

My `~/.basrhc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"
export PATH="/home/myuser/Programs/idea-IC-233.11799.241/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/myuser/Programs/visualvm_217/bin:$PATH"
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/all_configs_kube.conf
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.country=US"
```

Comment: I checked your `~/.bashrc` without the five `export` commands at the end. It works as you expect for me.

Comment: It also works with the `export` commands.

Comment: You didn't mention your terminal. I'm using kitty. Have you tried another terminal?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog `Open terminal (I'm using bash)`

Comment: Bash is the shell. The terminal is the application and it could be GNOME Terminal, Terminator, kitty, Tilix, etc.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog oh ok. I had no idea. Mine is GNOME Shell 42.9

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog anyway it does not work either on Intellij or VSCode terminals (which also worked previously)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog just tried Terminator, and the same applies

Comment: Here's a link to your previous question [Terminal autocomplete slash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1503611/terminal-autocomplete-slash) so we don't have to go through all the same troubleshooting steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

Apparently Coursier (from Scala) was installed on my computer, and it made a file (or whatever it was) always present: `.scala-cli.aux`, which made it always a candidate for autocomplete, preventing the slash to be written automatically. Uninstalling it made if work